# How does it affect True Pacifist by not giving Undyne the water - Undertale

Tags: undertale

I was watching a True Pacafist speedrun video (Like all of my questions start with me watching videos lol) When someone said it was crucial to give Undyne the water when she overheats in Hotland. What will happen if I don't give her the water?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Undyne's Wiki page](https://undertale.fandom.com/wiki/Undyne):

> If the protagonist leaves this room before pouring the water, Undyne develops heatstroke and the protagonist cannot befriend her, thus preventing the True Pacifist Route requirements from being fulfilled.